# File not uploading file over ssh if the size is under 200KB

Tags: java, file-upload, ssh, scp, jsch

I am trying to upload a file that is about 6kb to a ssh server. I have tried using the command on my terminal and even tested other commands and they work. Whats even weirder is that it will upload anything that is 200KB or bigger. I cant figure out what is going wrong but I suspect it has to do something with my while statement where I buffer it. (Note: I have tried different buf sizes.) Any help would be appreciated. (Note: everything is set up right so dont ask for my user info... I am also using jsch for my library)
No errors are shown when this is done... The file just doesnt show up at all in the ssh server.

```
public void testListener(FileUploadEvent event){
        InputStream fis = null;
        String lfile = event.getFile().getFileName();
            if(lfile.lastIndexOf('\\') > 0){
                lfile = lfile.substring(lfile.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            }

        String rfile =  "media/"+ lfile;
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, remotehost);
            session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect();
        boolean ptimestamp = false;

        String command="scp "+ (ptimestamp ? " -p " : "")+ "-t " + rfile;
        //String command = "cat > foo.txt";
        System.out.println(command);
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

        channel.connect();

        /*
        if(ptimestamp){
            command="T " +100 + " 0";
            command += (" " + 1000 + " 0\n");
            out.write(command.getBytes());
            out.flush();
        }

        */
        long filesize = event.getFile().getSize();

        command = "C0644 " + filesize + " " + lfile + "\n";
        out.write(command.getBytes());
        System.out.write(command.getBytes());
        out.flush();

        fis = event.getFile().getInputstream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len=0;
        while((len=fis.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) !=-1){
             //Change this remove break
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        fis.close();
        fis=null;

        buf[0]=0; 
        out.write(buf, 0, 1);
        out.flush();

        out.close();
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: What incorrect behavior are you seeing?  Error message? Exception? Program hangs? Resulting file is the wrong size? Blue screen of death?   I think we need some more details.

Comment: Like no error message or exception or anything happens the file doesnt appear on the ssh server even though no exceptions or anything were thrown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but it was only a work around...

```
 String command="cat >" + rfile +"; chmod 777 " + rfile +"; scp -t " + rfile;
```

I changed my command to create the file and it solved everything. I also removed the since the file is being created with cat. But no issues now thanks to everyone (no one) that helped.

```
command = "C0644 " + filesize + " " + lfile + "\n";
        out.write(command.getBytes());
        System.out.write(command.getBytes());
        out.flush();
```